# Hiding/Showing Element Based On View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to hide/show a div based on the users current view but I'm running into some issues. This is my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('RouteCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {

    $scope.currentPath = $location.path();
    console.log($location.path());

});
```

And in my index.html I have this:

```
<span ng-controller="RouteCtrl">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    <div ng-include="'views/siderail.html'" ng-hide="currentPath === '/live'" ></div>
 </span>
```

And in my `$routeProvider` I have this:

```
.when('/live', {
  templateUrl: 'views/live.html',
})
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to work. I want the div to be hidden when the site is on the /live route, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. It will work if I access the /live initially on load, but once the route changes it will not re-show the div, and vice versa. Almost as if it checks it once, instead of on every route change like I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to watch for location changes, because your scope variable is only defined once when controller is loaded.

Add the following code to your controller:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() { 
     $scope.currentPath = $location.path();
});
```

This will change your scope variable every time location changes.

Answer (score 0):

Include the controller in your route:

```
.when('/live', {
  controller: 'RouteCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'views/live.html',
})
```

Comment: That still doesn't do it. It works when I access the /live route on page load, but then if I return to the main route it wont show the div at all. It's checking on initial load, but not every time the view is changed. Does that make sense? I'll update the question.

Comment: Try displaying `{{ currentPath }}` on your page and see what it says as you change pages.